# Excel VBA: using HTML DOM

Tags: html, excel, internet-explorer, vba, dom

I need to know what all can I do with HTML over Excel VBA. for example I know that I can find element by id 
 `ie.document.getElementByID()`.
I will work with HTML table which doesn't have elements with id, so that it will look like `child->child->sibling->child.....` i think.

Can anybody pleas show me part of code, which will get text "hello" from this example table? first node will be found by his ID.

```
...
<table id="something">
  <tr>
    <td></td><td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td><td>hello</td>
  </tr>
...
```

Comment: What is your targets?

Comment: as I wrote. I need to find complete manual for working with HTML in Excel VBA. better that this will be in form for normal mortal man (I am not programming guru ;)

Comment: Here is the link to the [Microsoft DOM Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). As this is not really for mere mortals, I am not posting this as an answer ;) Good luck!

Comment: @grahamj42 thanks. I need this for VBA. I know that it is from the same "developer" (Microsoft :), so, just to make sure, is it the same thing?

Comment: Once you have a HTML document loaded, there is the same access to the object model that you would have using (eg) javascript on the client, so all you have to do is map the concepts to VBA (which is the easy part...) However, as grahamj42 notes, there's no easy "non-programmer" way into all of this. Try out a few things and post back - with code - if you have specific problems you can't solve.

Comment: okay, now I have HTML table. my target is for example get text in anchor on 188th line. in this example it is name "Vodrážka Rostislav, Ing."

code is available here: [link](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/5c325452)

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at this type of thing at the moment...

I believe the something like the below should do it:

```
ie.getelementbyid("something").getelementsbytagname("TD")(3).innertext
```

How it works:

It searches the HTML doc for the element where the ID is equal to "something" (will take first iteration if more than 1 but you can loop through many). It will then get take the table data tag and go to the iteration (3) where the text is (0 would equal the first TD).

Let us know if this works.

Comment: thanks for posting. it looks it should work. it's a year ago so I can't try it and I don't remember how I did sort out that thing. probably it was that way, but I really don't remember.

Answer (score -1):

Many HTML documents have names in generalized tables as opposed to ID's

I commonly use some form of what is shown below;

```
Set HTML = IE.Document
Set SomethingID = HTML.GetElementByID("something").Children
For Each TR in SomethingID
   If TR.TagName = "td" Then
      If TR.Name = "myname" Then
         'code in here if you are looking for a name to the element
      ElseIf TR.Value = "myValue" Then
         'Code in here if you are looking for a specific value
      ElseIf TR.innerText = "mytext" Then
         'more code in here if you are looking for a specific inner text
      End If
   End If
Next TR
```

Comment: Please format your code and add an explanation of what it dose